# Mapbox doesn't work in fragment

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I put mapbox in fragment but I can only see the title. Here is my code in fragment.

I can only see a gray screen with mapbox title. And I got no errors except emulator. Also, I tried to get Instance of MapBox in parent activity but it doesn't work either. I could sure use some help.

```
public class MapBox extends Fragment
{
    View root;
    MapView mapView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(),
                "pk.eyJ1IjoiYWNpaGFuayIsImEiOiJjamRobGVpdjUwd2tpMndtZmpsemxybjBjIn0.dmYB5bqnEqC57WqfH06hIQ");
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapbox_layout, container, false);

        return  root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mapView =(MapView) (root).findViewById(R.id.mapboxView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions for internet, fine location and access WiFi state like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And also set `ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`. You can also do it without `onViewCreated` - method and put it all in the `onCreateView` - method.

MapBox does also have a demo on [github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo). May this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer  i give the ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission but how can i set ACCESS_WIFI_STATE ?

Comment: You can set the permissions in the manifest-file. I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't clear. You don't have to set it in `onCreateView` - method.